# Use session data in Blade - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

I've created a new session in my controller and filled it with some data from my database.

Thats the controller code:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $products = Products::with('categories')->get()->take(5);
    $request->session()->put('session_products', $products);
    return view('shoppingcard.card');
}
```

and in the next controller function I retrieve the session data.

```
public function receiver(Request $request) {
    if($request->session()->has('session_products')) { 
        echo $request->session()->get('session_products'); 
    } 
    else return "stop no session"; 

    return view('shoppingcard.endview');
}
```

Now if I do a : `return $request->session()->get('session_products');` I get everything I need.

Here is a dummy data of the content from the session:

```
{"id":5,"title":"Beautiful Unicorn","price":"20.00","sale_price":"15.00","status":"active","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,}
```

Now I'm in the endview blade and want to output the Data.

How can I output specific Data like the "title" ?

Comment: oh and sorry, I'm new to the whole session, cookie thing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That data is serialized to session and unserialized back to a object. All you need is to use that info exactly the way you normally would:

```
public function receiver(Request $request) {
    if(! $request->session()->has('session_products')) {
        return "stop no session"; 
    }

    return view('shoppingcard.endview')
            ->with('title', $request->session()->get('session_products')[0]['title']);
}
```

Or you can just pass it all to your view:

```
public function receiver(Request $request) {
    if(! $request->session()->has('session_products')) {
        return "stop no session"; 
    }

    return view('shoppingcard.endview')
            ->with('products', $request->session()->get('session_products'));
}
```

And use it in the view:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{ $product['title'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: huh okay, I thought I could access the data without openting a new variable.. Sorry, I'm completly new to this.. But thanks alot!

Comment: Edited to add some options

Comment: yeah, thanks alot, I'm playing with that code snipped :)

Answer (score 1):

Well in order to access the title element you need to convert the json string to a array. To do this you need to use php's `json_decode` function to decode the string and then access the array like so:

```
$decodedJsonString = json_decode($request->session()->get('session_products'), true);
```

access it like `$decodedJsonString[id]['title'];`

[More about json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

UPDATE #1

use laravel's with() or compact() method to send it to the view

with() and compact are both eloquent methods

[More about eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent)

Comment: okay I will try it, but why using json_decode? I see it also works with the solution that @Antonio Carlos Riberio gave me - And thanks alot!

Comment: Well if you want to use it to display on the view then u have to convert it from (json) string to array so u can access each element but if you only want the full string then @antonio carlos answer is the best!

Comment: I see, thanks alot for all the help! This page is just awesome :)

Comment: Correction: the compact() method is not a Laravel/Eloquent method, it's a PHP method: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Answer (score 1):

your session save the products as json. you can decode it with json_decode, then access each of the products.

code as:

```
$products = json_decode($request->session()->get('session_products'), true);

foreach($products as $product)
{
  echo $product['title'];
}
```